# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/...txt

Tags: python-3.x, formal-verification

Trying to replicate the experiments in https://github.com/S3L-official/QEBVerif
However, encountering an error. Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thank you.

Running all three commands from the Readme file, throws File not found error, e.g.:
running
`_python3 DQVerifier_AcasXu_fixpoint.py --AcasNet 15 --property 4 --eps 0.01 --qu_bit 10 --error 0.1 --mode Sym --ifDiff 0 --outputPath output_`
throws

...

```
===== =====  ===== ===== Gurobi solving time is: 1375.9818675518036 ===== ===== ===== =====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DQVerifier_AcasXu_fixpoint.py", line 80, in <module>
    if_SAT, counterexample_QNN, counterexample_DNN, output_QNN, output_DNN = check_robustness_gurobi(
  File "/home/usr/Documents/git_QEBVerif/QEBVerif/gurobi_encoding/gurobi_encoding_DQ_AcasXu_FP.py", line 1072, in check_robustness_gurobi
    ifUNSat = encoding.sat(args, original_prediction)
  File "/home/usr/Documents/git_QEBVerif/QEBVerif/gurobi_encoding/gurobi_encoding_DQ_AcasXu_FP.py", line 563, in sat
    fo = open(args.outputPath + "/FP_" + str(args.property) + str("_Net_") + str(args.AcasNet) + "_qu_" + str(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/FP_4_Net_15_qu_10_eps_0.01_err_0.1_mode_Sym_ifDiff_0_gp.txt'
```